# Estoy construyendo un API REST en ASP.net y al ejecutar tengo un Object Reference not set

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, rest, asp.net-web-api

El mensaje de error específico indica: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Y me refiere al EntityClass que es donde están los metodos para interactuar con la base de datos, no importa que tipo de método utilice la excepcion siempre ocurre al guardar, agregar o traer a los usuarios para ingresar al sistema.

Este es mi controlador:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UsuariosController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("login")]
        public IActionResult Login(Credenciales model)
        {
            // Verificar si las credenciales son válidas
            Credenciales usuario = Credenciales.ObtenerInicioSesionPorId(model.CredencialesID ?? 0);
            if (usuario != null && usuario.Usuario == model.Usuario && usuario.Contraseña == model.Contraseña)
            {
                return Ok(new { message = "Inicio de sesión exitoso" });
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest(new { message = "Credenciales inválidas" });
            }
        }
        [HttpPost("registro")]
        public IActionResult Registro([FromBody] Credenciales model)
        {
            // Validar si los datos del modelo son válidos
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            try
            {
                // Realizar las operaciones necesarias para registrar el nuevo usuario
                model.CrearInicioSesion();

                // Devolver una respuesta exitosa con el nuevo usuario registrado
                return Ok(model);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Devolver un error en caso de que ocurra alguna excepción
                return StatusCode(500, $"Error al registrar el usuario: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
```

Este es mi modelo:

```
        {
            private const string TableName = "Credenciales";

            public int? CredencialesID { get; set; }
            public string Usuario { get; set; }
            public string Contraseña { get; set; }

            // Método para crear un nuevo inicio de sesión
            public void CrearInicioSesion()
            {
                Save(); // Guardar la instancia actual de Usuarios en la base de datos
            }

            // Método para obtener un inicio de sesión por su ID
            public static Credenciales ObtenerInicioSesionPorId(int id)
            {
                Credenciales inicioSesion = new Credenciales();
                List<Credenciales> iniciosSesion = inicioSesion.Get<Credenciales>("CredencialesID = " + id); // Obtener inicios de sesión con el ID especificado
                return iniciosSesion.Count > 0 ? iniciosSesion[0] : null; // Devolver el primer inicio de sesión encontrado o null si no hay coincidencias
            }

            // Método para obtener todos los inicios de sesión
            public static List<Credenciales> ObtenerTodosLosIniciosSesion()
            {
                Credenciales inicioSesion = new Credenciales();
                return inicioSesion.Get<Credenciales>(); // Obtener una lista de todos los inicios de sesión de la base de datos
            }
        }
    }
```

Cuando ejecuto localmente el API con IIS y pruebo la validación desde swagger es cuando el API me muestra esto: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El cuadro de dialogo para los detalles muestra esto: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución no fue la más practica, pero por fines educativos me funciono y es agregar dentro de los métodos del modelo la validación de las credenciales del SSMS, anteriormente se logueaba usando las credenciales de la máquina.

La estructura génerica fue llamar desde el ADOConexion un Innit y las credenciales de un usuario cualquiera como el sa.

Por ejemplo:

```
public static void CrearInicioSesion(Credenciales credenciales)
        {
            SqlADOConexion.IniciarConexion("sa", "123456789");
            credenciales.Save();
        }
```